# Ajax error, Object function bound has no method 'ajax'

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I have simple Ajax request, but for some reason it gives some error. I don't have a clue what this error means:

```
TypeError: Object function bound(var_args) { return func.apply(thisObject, args.concat(slice(arguments))); } has no method 'ajax'
```

It's trying to access PHP function where it gets data.

Here is the ajax request itself:

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'http://me.mydomain.com/get-ajax.php',
    data: {
        'action': 'request',
        'id': 314
    },
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(data) {
        console.log(data['post']);
    }
});
```

Comment: Have you added jQuery to the page. This will not work without jQuery.

Comment: just do console.log(data); and check does error repeat.

Comment: Console.log in success? It doesn't log because it gives this typerror.

Comment: I guess he has added jquery, or else this notice would,nt had been shown. args.concat is inbuilt in jquery.js library

Comment: Oh, seems that this happens on just some of the pages. If I do it front page it works perfectly. Perhaps some conflict with query on some pages.

Comment: use `jQuery` in place of `$`. It might be conflicting with some other library.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure your jQuery script is loaded when you make this ajax call, as @mesutozer said, if that doesn't help then I assume you have some additional javascript that could be using $ shortcut so try **jQuery.ajax({...})** instead

Answer (score 0):

Enclose your $.ajax call within jQuery's document ready callback to make sure it is executed when jQuery is loaded

```
$(document).ready(function (){
  $.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'http://me.mydomain.com/get-ajax.php',
    data: {
        'action': 'request',
        'id': 314
    },
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(data) {
        console.log(data['post']);
    }
  }); 
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess your jquery is conflicting.
try-

```
$m=jQuery.noConflict(); // write it at the top

$m.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'http://me.mydomain.com/get-ajax.php',
    data: {
        'action': 'request',
        'id': 314
    },
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(data) {
        console.log(data['post']);
    }
});
```